# Unable to start guidewire CC server from tomcat

Tags: guidewire, gosu

We have been trying to start the claimcenter server from tomcat. The server is getting started even though it throws exception with the message "ClaimCenter unable to start" in the logs. Please find the log details below.
gw.pl.exception.GWLifecycleException: An exception was thrown while starting a component. Setting runlevel to NODAEMONS
Caused by: gw.pl.exception.GWLifecycleException:Messaging plugin does not implement MessageTransport interface error

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes -

1. The xyzMessageTransport class failed to instantiate due to invalid parameters.
2. A class which is not implementation of MessageTransport inteface configured under
   MessageTransport plugin. check messaging-config.xml.

Also - specify plugin name or attach whole log if possible.